# Checking text in Rich textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I'm using a Rich Textbox in my vb.net application on update form to take address value. My update query is generated at run time looping through the textboxes on the form and checking which fields have got some value and the corresponding fields are updated in the database.

```
For Each x As Control In Me.Controls

        If x.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Or x.GetType Is GetType(MaskedTextBox) Or x.GetType Is GetType(RichTextBox) Then
            If Not x.Name = "party_code" Then

                'if user has not entered a value in a textbox then incremnets the flag variable

                If (x.Text = String.Empty) Or ((x.Name = "contact1" Or x.Name = "contact2" Or x.Name = "ptcl") And (x.Text.Trim().EndsWith("-") And x.Text.Trim().StartsWith("-"))) Then
                    flag += 1
                End If

                'checks if the user has entered a value in some textbox 

                If (Not x.Text = String.Empty And Not x.Name = "contact1" And Not x.Name = "contact2" And Not x.Name = "ptcl") Or ((x.Name = "contact1" Or x.Name = "contact2" Or x.Name = "ptcl") And Not x.Text.Trim.EndsWith("-")) Then


                    'generates query text for the textbox which contains some value

                    str = str & comma & x.Name & " = @" & x.Name

                    comma = " , "
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next
```

I'm also using Enter key to shift focus to next textbox on the form. When the focus reaches Adress Rich textbox and I don't have to update address field in database and i press Enter key to move to next textbox then the above code tracks that Address Rich Textbox has got some new value i.e. the Enter Key and updates the address field in the database. How can i get rid of this issue??

Code behind shifting Focus:

```
 Private Sub town_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles town.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then
        address.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub address_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles address.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then
        Button3.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

I've handled it through Keydown event..!!

Comment: Clearly your "shift focus on Enter key" code is broken.  You didn't post it but my crystal ball says that you forgot to use the Handled or SuppressKeyPress property.

Comment: I've added the code on keydown event which handles the shifting of focus...Please tell about the problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are changing focus in your town_KeyDown Handle the KeyDownEvent like this use [`e.Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled.aspx) this will prevent the keypress from being further processed.

i.e.

```
Private Sub town_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles town.KeyDown 
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Return Then 
        address.Focus() 
        e.Handled = True
        Exit Sub
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: done the same thing but when focus shifts from adress to button3.....i.e. in the keydown event of address Rich Textbox....Thanks anyways

Comment: @user944591 I see you figured out what I meant. Anytime you handle the `KeyDown` event by yourself make sure that you use e.Handle to tell the system to ignore it..

Comment: In this case what does e.handle actually do i mean what functionality will it perform??

Comment: It means that you handled the keydown key and it does not need to be passed on. It has been "handled". [If the event is not handled, it will be sent to the operating system for default processing. Set Handled to true to cancel the KeyPress event.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx)